# Accessing online xml with python

Tags: python, xml

I am trying to access an xml file (many actually) from an online source. I had a code that would do it but i installed a fresh OS and forgot to back up my phython scripts :(

I am literally just trying to access the xml, once I have the data i believe i remember how i parsed it. I just can't remember how i accessed it. I've been looking around and all i can find is stuff in the urllib but when i try to make a request it wont run the script because of the ':' in the web address. Any help??

here is one of the xml addresses I'm trying to access.
http://api.eve-central.com/api/marketstat?typeid=34&regionlimit=10000002

Comment: http://developer.yahoo.com/python/python-xml.html

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The urllib2 library is what you are looking for.

http://docs.python.org/2/howto/urllib2.html

Briefly, this is how you use itL

```
url_response = urllib2.urlopen(url) ## return a http.response object 
xml_content = url_response.read() ## read the content
```

In addition, I uses beautifulsoup4 to pull out data from the xml doc http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/ .

Briefly,

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup           ## import bs4 as BeautifulSoup
content = BeautifulSoup(xml_content)    ## convert xml content to beautifulsoup object 
span = content.find_all("span")         ## find all span tag and return as list
```

Cheer!

Comment: im using 3.3 so no urllib2. When I use urllib.request.urlopen(...) it just returns an object ("http.client.HTTPResponse object"), not the xml data.

Comment: Hi there,i have edited by answer that shows how you may get the xml data. Cheers!